# Java array storing more than the upper bound

Tags: java, arrays

I was under the impression that storing and accessing data beyond the upper bound specified for arrays will result in Exception but I was coding a solution and I stumbled upon a scenario where the array stored more elements than the upper bound.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[1][5];
        String values = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
        arr[0] = Arrays.asList(values.split(" ")).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        for (int i : arr[0]) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

The above program outputs `1 2 3 4 5 6` in separate lines while clearly I have specified my upperbound as 5. Can someone explain this weird phenomenon?

Comment: `a[0]` is just a reference to an array, initialized to a new array of size 5. You change the reference to a new array of size 6.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Ohh basically then it treats as an array initialization rather than an assignment then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain this weird phenomenon?

Here goes:

```
    int[][] arr = new int[1][5];
```

is declaring an `int[][]` and initializing it to a structure consisting of one top-level `int[][]` of length 1, and one second level `int[]` subarray of length 5.  The first cell of the former refers to the latter.

Then:

```
    arr[0] = Arrays.asList(values.split(" "))
                   .stream()
                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                   .toArray();
```

is creating an `int[]` of length 6 and assigning it to `arr[0]`.   This *replaces* the `int[]` subarray of length 5 that was created in the earlier initialization.

The intuitive behavior is that the "shape" of `arr` changes from a `int[1][5]` to `int[1][6]` when you do that assignment.

---

You then commented:

> "Ohh basically then it treats as an array initialization rather than an assignment then."

Strictly, no. If you think of `arr[0] = ...` as an array *initialization*, it gets confusing.  It is actually an assignment of a newly create array of type `int[]` to a cell of an existing "array of `int[]`".

This may sound like a fine distinction, but it goes to the heart of the matter.  If you read the JLS and the JVM specs deeply, you will see that Java array types and objects are fundamentally one dimensional.  Thus `int[][]` is a syntactic shorthand<sup>1</sup> for "array of `int[]`", and `arr[i][j]` is a shorthand for `(arr[i])[j]`.

Thus when we do `arr[0] = ...` in the example, we are not initializing something.  Instead, we are changing a data structure that was initialized previously.  At least, that is the Java language perspective.

From the perspective of the class where this is happening, this could be getting something into the initial state that is required by the class semantics.  Thus it is reasonable to call that "initialization" ... from that perspective.

---

<sup>1 - This shorthand is so ingrained in the language that there isn't any other way to write the type "array of `int[]`" using Java syntax.  The syntax for array types comes from C via C++, though the particular Java semantics of arrays doesn't.</sup>

Comment: Hey Stephen thanks for the answer it cleared my doubts

Answer (score 0):

After assignment, `arr[0]` is holding a list object that has bounds set to whatever `Arrays.asList` defines.